# ¿Cómo es que incrementa el uso de la memoria de forma dinámica al utilizar listas enlazadas?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Llevo actualmente curso de Estructura de Datos en Java y ocupo saber cómo se comporta la memoria.

No entiendo qué pasa cuando se almacena la información, ya sea cuando le dices `Nodo Fin = null` o `inicio = siguiente` o `siguiente = fin`.

Todas esas especificaciones las entiendo, pero no sé qué pasa.

¿Cómo toma las referencias, si quiero guardar más datos, por ejemplo `Integer` y también un `String`?

Ando bien confundido con esto de los nodos y punteros, con esto de listas enlazadas y doblemente enlazadas.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que no te queda claro son las asignaciones de punteros a distintos nodos de una lista, por ejemplo. Hay que tener claro que los punteros almacenan un lugar de memoria (a dónde apuntan). Cuando los asignamos al primer elemento de una lista por ejemplo, lo que estamos haciendo es "apuntarlo" al lugar de memoria donde se encuentra el primer elemento de la lista.

Java maneja la reserva y liberacion de memoria por nosotros a diferencia de lenguajes como C. Cuando hacemos

```
List lista = new ArrayList();
```

Estamos creando un nuevo espacio de memoria que ocupa el nuevo `ArrayList` y `lista` apunta hacia dicho espacio.

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean addDato(Object dato) { 
    Nodo nodoUltimo = getUltimoNodo(); 
    if(dato != null && nodoUltimo != null) { 
        nodoUltimo.setNodo(new Nodo(dato)); //New pide mas memoria para dato en un nuevo nodo
        tamaño ++; 
        return true; 
    }else{
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Si haces `Lista list = new Lista();` ahí pides más memoria para almacenar `list`. Pero si haces `list=null;` aunque el contenido de la lista sigue en memoria ya se perdió la referencia a `list` y el recolector de basura de java reclamará la memoria cuando se ejecute, y libera la memoria.

Lo mismo ocurre al hacer `Nodo Fin = null` dentro de la programación interna de una lista.

Cuando haces `inicio = siguiente` solo avanzas del nodo cabecera al nodo posición cero.

Cuando haces `siguiente = fin`  quiere decir que estás en el último nodo y entonces lo apuntas a `null` porque ahí termina la lista.

Revisa el diagrama de cajitas de esta página y entenderas lo que te explico.
http://usandojava.blogspot.mx/2011/12/implementacion-de-una-lista-simple.html#sthash.cNm27jPo.dpuf

Y recuerda algo muy importante esto es java no c++, **aquí no hay apuntadores**, aqui los apuntadores solo existen en los diagramas de cajas con los que te explican cómo funcionan las listas.

Answer (score 1):

Java no permite una gestión de memoria como otros lenguajes del tipo C o C++, donde tu reservas memoria, y además puedes moverte a traves de la memoria reservada, realizar aritmetica de punteros y demás cosas....

La máquina virtual Java(JVM) implementa un mecanismo llamado Garbage Collector(GC) que realiza una gestión automática de la memoria. Es el GC el que reserva memoria, libera memoria en funcion de ciertos criterios, etc.

Cuando tu creas un objeto con algo como esto:

```
String texto="Hola Mundo";
```

Tu nunca vas a poder reservar memoria para esa referencia, no vas a saber donde se ubica ni nada de ese estilo. Puedes invocar al GC de forma programatica por medio de llamadas a **System.gc() o Runtime.gc()** pero no se garantiza cuando se ejecutara y lo que se eliminara.

Por otro lado, si necesitas una estructura de datos como una pila, lista, lista enlazada, diccionario o mapa, etc Java ya te ofrece implementaciones básicas de esas estructuras, además como se basan en ciertos interfaces tu puedes hacer tu propia implementacion si fuera necesario.

Por ejemplo, si buscas en la documentación del JDK el interface *java.util.List* puedes ver las clases que lo implementan y como representan diferentes estructuras de datos: *Stack, Vector, ArrayList, LinkedList, etc*

Por ultimo, te puedes preguntar que pasa si por ejemplo creo tantos objetos que agoto la memoria disponible, si no tengo control sobre la gestión de la memoria que va a pasar...., bueno pues para eso Java te permite configurar la JVM para que tenga un tamaño máximo de memoria disponible y un tamaño de memoria inicial entre otros. Con esto basicamente se dimensiona el tamaño del *Heap* y del *Permgen* utilizados por la JVM que son las zonas de memoria donde se ubican los objetos.

Si se agota la memoria del Heap o del Permgen, se producira un error del tipo ***java.lang.OutOfMemoryError***. Esto significa o que tienes un problema con objetos que nunca se liberan o que necesitas más memoria para la ejecución de tu aplicación

Te animo a que investigues más por tu cuenta, el tema da para mucho.